Problems with ee_to_df() function in geemap
I'm revisiting some old Jupyter notebooks that I had set up to download Google Earth Engine data with geemap. I had a workflow that used the geemap.ee_to_pandas() function pretty heavily, which now seems to be deprecated and replaced by geemap.ee_to_df().
When I use that new function, however, I now get the error:
Exception: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fileFormat": Cannot find field.
What can I do to fix this? It used to work just fine. I've updated my geemap account to link it with a Google Cloud account, if that has anything to do with it.
Sample code:
def pointExtraction(image):
    feature = image.sampleRegions(
        collection = collection,
        scale = 10 
    )
    return feature

point_extract = pointExtraction(image)
point_vals = geemap.ee_to_df(point_extract)

